# Сделать перечисление из enum и не только

Tags: javascript, enum

Как сделать такую конструкцию:

```
var sub = { ops: 'opsfe-efe', sut: 'sut-efe'} 
var params = {
  {sub.ops, 'мое значение'},
  {sub.sut, 'еще одно мое значение' }
}
```

а потом еще и взять все параметры из `params` в цикле?

Можно ли как-то по простому, данная конструкция не работает в javascript?

Comment: что ожидается увидеть в params? Два поля со значением объект?

Comment: какой конечный вид должен принять params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать примерно так:

```
var sub = { ops: 'opsfe-efe', sut: 'sut-efe'};
var params = [
  {id: sub.ops, val: 'мое значение'},
  {id: sub.sut, val: 'еще одно мое значение' }
];
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает